# Moving files in Filezilla gives Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: ssh, ftp, amazon-web-services, sftp, filezilla

I generated a new SSH key for my AWS instance on my local machine (with passphrase). Then SSHed into it and uploaded my public key in the `authorized_keys`.

I was able to **connect and move files (get & put)** successfully through the terminal (STFP). In FileZilla however, I was able to connect and view all files and move from my local machine to the server, **but not from the server to my local machine**. FileZilla keeps showing:

`Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`

What is the cause of this?

**Update: Log**

```
Status:         Connecting to 35.181.**.***...
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:          Going to execute /Applications/FileZilla.app/Contents/MacOS//fzsftp
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::ParseResponse() in state 0
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    keyfile "/Users/****/Desktop/svParis.ppk"
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    open "ubuntu@35.181.**.***" 22
Trace:          Connecting to 35.181.**.*** port 22
Trace:          We claim version: SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.43.0
Trace:          Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
Trace:          Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:          Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
Trace:          Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Trace:          Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:          ssh-ed25519 256 62:2b:a1:ac:13:74:1a:c5:56:bf:82:74:d0:28:e2:8c HnCtld7UjEMzLCnnbrUUy9EVFmFMHI0fg7QnLBzqbCk=
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::SetAsyncRequestReply
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM client->server encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM client->server MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM server->client encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM server->client MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Trace:          Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
Trace:          Private key in '/Users/****/Desktop/svParis.ppk' is encrypted, defer loading until use.
Trace:          Successfully loaded 1 key pair from file
Trace:          Offered public key from "/Users/****/Desktop/svParis.ppk"
Trace:          Offer of public key accepted, trying to authenticate using it.
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::SetAsyncRequestReply
Command:    Pass: ***********
Trace:          Access granted
Trace:          Opening session as main channel
Trace:          Opened main channel
Trace:          Started a shell/command
Status:         Connected to 35.181.**.***
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Trace:          CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Reset(0) in state 3
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpListOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:          CSftpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:          CSftpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    pwd
Response:   Current directory is: "/home/ubuntu"
Trace:          CSftpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:          CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:          CSftpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 1
Trace:          CSftpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpListOpData::Send() in state 2
Trace:          CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:          CSftpListOpData::Reset(0) in state 2
Status:         Directory listing of "/home/ubuntu" successful
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status:         Disconnected from server
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status:         Connecting to 35.181.**.***...
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:          Going to execute /Applications/FileZilla.app/Contents/MacOS//fzsftp
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::ParseResponse() in state 0
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    keyfile "/Users/****/Desktop/ParisInstance.ppk"
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    open "ubuntu@35.181.**.***" 22
Trace:          Connecting to 35.181.**.*** port 22
Trace:          We claim version: SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.43.0
Trace:          Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
Trace:          Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:          Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
Trace:          Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Trace:          Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:          ssh-ed25519 256 62:2b:a1:ac:13:74:1a:c5:56:bf:82:74:d0:28:e2:8c HnCtld7UjEMzLCnnbrUUy9EVFmFMHI0fg7QnLBzqbCk=
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::SetAsyncRequestReply
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM client->server encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM client->server MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM server->client encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM server->client MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Trace:          Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
Trace:          Successfully loaded 1 key pair from file
Trace:          Offered public key from "/Users/****/Desktop/ParisInstance.ppk"
Trace:          Server refused our key
Trace:          Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:          Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::OnTerminate without error
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Reset(66) in state 3
Error:          Could not connect to server
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
Status:         Disconnected from server
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status:         Delaying connection for 5 seconds due to previously failed connection attempt...
Status:         Connecting to 35.181.**.***...
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:          Going to execute /Applications/FileZilla.app/Contents/MacOS//fzsftp
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::ParseResponse() in state 0
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    keyfile "/Users/****/Desktop/ParisInstance.ppk"
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    open "ubuntu@35.181.**.***" 22
Trace:          Connecting to 35.181.**.*** port 22
Trace:          We claim version: SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.43.0
Trace:          Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
Trace:          Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:          Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
Trace:          Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Trace:          Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:          ssh-ed25519 256 62:2b:a1:ac:13:74:1a:c5:56:bf:82:74:d0:28:e2:8c HnCtld7UjEMzLCnnbrUUy9EVFmFMHI0fg7QnLBzqbCk=
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::SetAsyncRequestReply
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM client->server encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM client->server MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM server->client encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM server->client MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Trace:          Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
Trace:          Successfully loaded 1 key pair from file
Trace:          Offered public key from "/Users/****/Desktop/ParisInstance.ppk"
Trace:          Server refused our key
Trace:          Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:          Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::OnTerminate without error
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Reset(66) in state 3
Error:          Could not connect to server
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
Status:         Disconnected from server
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Status:         Delaying connection for 5 seconds due to previously failed connection attempt...
Status:         Connecting to 35.181.**.***...
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:          Going to execute /Applications/FileZilla.app/Contents/MacOS//fzsftp
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::ParseResponse() in state 0
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    keyfile "/Users/****/Desktop/ParisInstance.ppk"
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:          CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Send() in state 3
Command:    open "ubuntu@35.181.**.***" 22
Trace:          Connecting to 35.181.**.*** port 22
Trace:          We claim version: SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.43.0
Trace:          Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
Trace:          Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:          Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
Trace:          Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Trace:          Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:          ssh-ed25519 256 62:2b:a1:ac:13:74:1a:c5:56:bf:82:74:d0:28:e2:8c HnCtld7UjEMzLCnnbrUUy9EVFmFMHI0fg7QnLBzqbCk=
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::SetAsyncRequestReply
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM client->server encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM client->server MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Initialised AES-256 GCM server->client encryption
Trace:          Initialised AES256 GCM server->client MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:          Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Trace:          Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys
Trace:          Successfully loaded 1 key pair from file
Trace:          Offered public key from "/Users/****/Desktop/ParisInstance.ppk"
Trace:          Server refused our key
Trace:          Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:          Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::OnTerminate without error
Trace:          CControlSocket::DoClose(66)
Trace:          CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:          CSftpDeleteOpData::Reset(66) in state 3
Error:          Could not connect to server
Trace:          CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66)
```

FileZilla version: 3.43.0 (latest)
OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

The connection was successful as you see in `Directory listing of "/var/www/html" successful`, then I moved a file (from server to my local) and I keep getting the error.

**Update 2:**
Now I can see the problem. FileZilla used svParis.ppk to connect at first, then when I'm trying to move the files, it uses ParisInstance.ppk (the old key I changed).

Why is this happening? Is it because I added the public key to my instance manually (not from AWS console)?

Comment: I can confirm that FileZilla generally works for this, I've done exactly the same ting. We'll need more detail to help - ssh detailed logs, any FileZilla logs, and FileZilla platform / version - latest is 3.43.0.

Comment: Now I can see the problem. FileZilla used svParis.ppk to connect at first, then when I'm trying to move the files, it uses ParisInstance.ppk (the old key I changed). But why ?

Comment: FileZilla cannot made the file name up. Scan the FileZilla configuration files (`filezilla.xml` and its companions) for the `ParisInstance.ppk`. - It should be in `~/.config/filezilla` on MacOS (https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=34904)

Comment: Thank you very much. removing the folder solved it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved by** removing the `~/.config/fiezilla` folder while FileZilla was closed.

**Why:**
Scanning the config folder, showed my old key `ParisInstance.ppk` was still written into one of the files (`filezilla.xml`), though `sitemanager.xml` had the correct key.
However, after removing the folder, starting FileZilla, and adding the server connection info again it worked.

Comment: Where did you find your key in `sitemanager.xml`? I'm not aware that it's possible to specify a key for a specific site in FileZilla.

Comment: In the Site Manager window, Using SFTP with logon type "Key file" allows you to specify the key file (file path) and it will be stored in the `sitemanager.xml` inside `<Keyfile>` tags.

Comment: OK, I see. Then it's obvious how to fix this cleanly, instead of deleting all your FileZilla configuration.

Comment: I had the new key stored in `sitemanager.xml`, but the problem was that the old key stored in `filezilla.xml`. Not sure why the old one was there.